Download blobs as batch
Can I download the blobs in batches? For instance, if I have 1000 files, can I segregate them into 10 batches, with each batch containing 100 files? I want to call the function or method only 10 times instead of downloading each blob one by one.
Download files in 10 batches, each with 100 files. Call function 10 times for efficient retrieval, not individually.

What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to download files from google cloud storage? If so, are you doing this via code or are you using the CLI?
